# Does Enum.into and Map.new create new objects in memory?

Tags: dictionary, object, memory, elixir

```
weekdays = [:monday, :tuesday, :wednesday, :thursday, :friday, :saturday, :sunday] 
|> Enum.with_index 

Map.new(weekdays)
Enum.into(weekdays, %{})
```

Does `Map.new/1` and `Enum.into/2` do absolutely the same thing here?
How many objects will be in memory after executing following code:
`weekdays |> Map.new |> Map.new` and `weekdays |> Enum.into(%{}) |> Enum.into(%{})`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not profiled to see the difference, however `Enum.into` relies on the [Collectable protocol](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Collectable.html), which for maps [calls `Map.put` for each element](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/8fa1bb519582dce7d559afe41d959ae76d52305e/lib/elixir/lib/collectable.ex#L163-L177). However, `Map.new` [uses Erlang's `:maps.from_list`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.11.3/lib/elixir/lib/map.ex#L189), which is [implemented in C](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/erts/emulator/beam/erl_map.c#L268-L301).

So I suspect `Map.new` will be more performant.